# Need help from scratch with getting apps running on my iPod Touch and to upload apps to the app store

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

I really need help with this. This time 2 days ago, my app was going onto my ipod touch fine. I followed a tutorial to put it on the app store. Errors. Tried fixing them, more errors. I deleted all the keys and followed tutorial after tutorial on how to get it working but i'm just getting so many code signing errors, and this is all i've been dealing with over the past two days. I can't even build to my ipod anymore. Apple need's to sort this out, because it's beyond stupid and ridiculous.

I'm the 'team leader', as i'm the only member of my team. Can somebody link me to a decent tutorial or give a rundown of what i need to do in order to get my app running on my ipod touch again, and get it on the app store. I'm really at my wits end with this. I have no idea what i'm supposed to do now.

Comment: What are the errors You are getting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the URL [How to Build](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/24/tutorial-list-guideline-for-building-ad-hoc-application-for-iphone/)

From above link instead of selecting adhoc profile, select developer profile. That's the only difference.

Its pretty easy if you understand step by step of what Apple gave in documentation. I agree that it seems to be difficult procedure for a fresher. I too felt like that. But when I understood the flow, its a 2 minute job for me.